# php session can not pass variable to other page

Tags: php, session, variables

I have a formal code, but the session variable can't be passed to another page.
So here is my sample code. However, the result of this code is 0.:

page1 code:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['try'] = 5;
header('Location: page2.php');
?>
```

page2 code:

```
<?php
session_start();
$test = $_SESSION['try'];
echo $test;
?>
```

Comment: Are cookies turned off? If so then you need to pass your session_id into your session

Comment: Cookies have nothing to do with `$_SESSION` variables

Comment: Doesn't $test have to have double equals sign?

Comment: And @adamd yes they do session automatically creates a cookie and only uses a session if the I'd is passed through

Comment: @AdamD huh? You may want to read up on the topic.

Comment: Cookies are used for sessions exclusively since php 5.3 unless you set session.use_only_cookies = 0

Comment: Thank you I was just researching clarification of that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [*manual*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php):

```
session_start() creates a session or resumes the current 
one based on a session identifier passed via a GET or POST request, 
or passed via a cookie.
```

pay attention to the last two lines of code:

```
<?php
// page1.php

session_start();

echo 'Welcome to page #1';

$_SESSION['favcolor'] = 'green';
$_SESSION['animal']   = 'cat';
$_SESSION['time']     = time();

// Works if session cookie was accepted
echo '<br /><a href="page2.php">page 2</a>';

// Or maybe pass along the session id, if needed
echo '<br /><a href="page2.php?' . SID . '">page 2</a>';
?>
```

Comment: Also from [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-only-cookies) - session.use_only_cookies specifies whether the module will only use cookies to store the session id on the client side. Enabling this setting prevents attacks involved passing session ids in URLs. This setting was added in PHP 4.3.0. Defaults to 1 (enabled) since PHP 5.3.0.

Comment: Thank you. I tested the code. After I clicked "page 2", the result is still 0, which means no value of the session variable passed to the 2nd page.

Comment: in page2 do `var_dump($_SESSION);` and check if anything has passed at all.

Comment: Thank you, but the result is: array(0) { }.

Comment: Run `phpinfo()` and check the session settings. Also, check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8977032/1057429

Comment: Where should I run phpinfo()?

Comment: create a new php file and put there `<?php echo phpinfo;?>`

Comment: here are some of the session settings       session

Session Support  enabled  
Registered save handlers  files user sqlite  
Registered serializer handlers  php php_binary wddx  



Directive

Local Value

Master Value

session.auto_start Off Off 
session.bug_compat_42 Off Off 
session.bug_compat_warn Off Off 
session.cache_expire 180 180 
session.cache_limiter nocache nocache 
session.cookie_domain no value no value 
session.cookie_httponly Off Off 
session.cookie_lifetime 0 0 
session.cookie_path / / 
session.cookie_secure Off Off 
session.entropy_file /dev/urandom /dev/urandom

Comment: what should I pay attention to in the settings

Comment: look for `session.save_path` and make sure this folder has write permissions

Comment: sorry to give you so much work. in my setting, the session.save_path is : /var/php_sessions, how can I know the folder's permissions

Comment: run from command prompt (ssh): `ls -l /var/ | grep php_sessions`

Comment: The command doesn't work: C:\users\xxx\.ssh> ls -l /var/ | grep php_sessions    'ls' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable file, or batch program

Comment: It looks like you're working on a windows machine and the path is a unix style path... Try creating a folder for the sessions to be stored  and update your `php.ini` file with that path.

Comment: Thanks. I am using i-page remote server. That's probably why the path is a unix style. What can I do in this case?

Comment: it solved, I contact with I-page, they set up the session permission for me, my code works now.

Comment: Thank you everyone. Thank you alfasin. I thought I have hope to solve the problem when you give me hint every time. The feeling is good. Thanks

Comment: another question: I want to pass parameter now between 2 pages, in page1:  ..........                                                 $problem  = "correct";                                         header('Location:trynew2.php?problem=$problem');                  in page 2: ...  
$problem = $_GET['problem'];
echo $problem;     ........... but couldn't display "correct"