# Not able to determine when session is active in PHP

Tags: php, session

So I want to be able to tell, in PHP, whether a session is currently active. I thought that this would be easy by either using `session_status()` or `session_id()`, but both return inconclusive results.

My PHP looks like this

```
if (session_id() == "") {
    echo json_encode("nope");
} else {
    echo json_encode("yep");
}

if (session_status() === PHP_SESSION_DISABLED) {
    echo json_encode("disabled");
} elseif (session_status() === PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    echo json_encode("none");
} else {
    echo json_encode("active");
}

$handler = new DatabaseSessionHandler();
session_set_save_handler($handler, true);
session_start();
```

And I have an Angular app making http calls to this script to basically activate its session.

I've been testing this, and when I visit the site for the first time, no `session_id` is found and the `session_status()` returns back `"none"`, as they both should. But the problem is, when I refresh the page, and this PHP script is runs, but this time I have an active session (the PHP session cookie shows up in my browser), `session_id` is still acting like none exists. And also, `session_status()` returns back, mistakenly `"none"`.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Edit 1: A few people have mentioned that putting the `session_start()` in front of testing if it is active or not should work. When I do this, a `session_id` is always found, and the `session_status()` always returns back `"active"`. Even when a fresh new user visits the site, this still happens.

Answer (score 1):

The session won't be active until you call `session_start()`, which you don't do until after testing to see if the session is active.

Answer (score 0):

You should  call `session_start()` at Top of the page and then perform the condition on it. In your case you are not starting session and you are testing for  it.

Comment: I can't see your edit I see only your previous code.

Comment: A few people have mentioned that putting the `session_start()` in front of testing if it is active or not should work. When I do this, a `session_id` is always found, and the `session_status()` always returns back `"active"`. Even when a fresh new user visits the site, this still happens.

Comment: Now what is the problem if you are getting your status active, Sorry if I've not understand your problem, clarify your problem.

Comment: I want to be able to tell a fresh new user, one that doesn't currently have a session, from a user that already has a session. I mean what's the point of `session_status()` if it always returns `PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE` since the function is called after `session_start()`?

Comment: Hope this help.
<?php
if (session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {session_start();}
?>

Comment: Sorry, I guess I missed this comment but, I already tried this. Before I call `session_start()`, `session_status()` **always** returns back `PHP_SESSION_NONE`, so this won't work.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if this will solve your problem, but you could check if your session directory is writable:

```
if (!is_writable(session_save_path())) {
    echo 'Session path "'.session_save_path().'" is not writable for PHP!'; 
}
```

A question related to that is at [PHP Session not Saving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8976930/php-session-not-saving).

Elsewhere try the following:

```
if (session_id() == "") {
    session_start();
    echo json_encode("nope");
} else {
    echo json_encode("yep");
}
```